# Creating a character set of alphabets for various language

Tags: qt, character-encoding, internationalization, qml, character

How can I create a character set for several languages with their corresponding alphabets?
What I intend to do, is have separate strings of these alphabets, then have a flag that determines which set to use based on the language chosen. I want to do this in Qml but I have no idea how to approach this. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html? I would say you put a qsTr() with the whole alphabet and then the translators give their version.

Comment: https://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 0):

Unicode (which is the encoding typically used for text in modern applications) maps different writing systems or alphabets to different ranges of code points. For instance, all values between 0 and 127 are "basic latin". Wikipedia has [the full set of blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block).

QML supports adding characters as raw Unicode values by escaping them with "\u". For instance, if you would like a Greek lower-case "beta" symbol, you could check [the Greek/Coptic range in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic), see that lower-case beta is mapped to U+03B2 and show this with the following code:

```
Text {
   text: "Here is a beta-symbol: \u03B2"
}
```